# Robolectric ListFragment behavior differs on device, throws null while testing

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment, robolectric

I am trying to set up a basic test for a ListFragment and am running into serious issues. I'd been getting strange behavior out of Robolectric ListFragments, so I decided to run them on the device. They appear to be working precisely as I intended on the actual device, but not so with Robolectric. I'm using 2.3 snapshot 20140425.145412-162-jar-with-dependencies, because we need to use non-support Fragments.

When I run the ListFragment on the device, everything is dandy. When I run it on Robolectric, I get a null pointer exception at `ListFragment$1.run(ListFragment.java:153)`. I've tried adding my own `startFragment` method and using the one provided in `FragmentTestUtil`.

This appears to be a bug, because even if I was doing something wrong I would expect behavior to be identical on the device.

Here is my ListFragment class:

```
public class TableManagerFragment extends ListFragment {

  private static final String TAG = TableManagerFragment.class.getSimpleName();

  /** All the TableProperties that should be visible to the user. */
  private List<TableProperties> mTableList;

  private TablePropertiesAdapter mTpAdapter;

  public TableManagerFragment() {
    // empty constructor required for fragments.
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "[onCreate]");
    this.mTableList = new ArrayList<TableProperties>();
    this.setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    this.setMenuVisibility(true);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Log.d(TAG, "[onOptionsItemSelected] selecting an item");
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(
      LayoutInflater inflater,
      ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "[onCreateView]");
    View view = inflater.inflate(
        R.layout.fragment_table_list,
        container,
        false);
    return view;
  }

  @Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // call this here because we need a context.
    List<TableProperties> newProperties = this.retrieveContentsToDisplay();
    Log.e(TAG, "got newProperties list of size: " + newProperties.size());
    this.setPropertiesList(newProperties);
    this.mTpAdapter = new TablePropertiesAdapter(this.getPropertiesList());
    this.setListAdapter(this.mTpAdapter);
    this.mTpAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();    
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.table_manager, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
  }

  /**
   * Retrieve the contents that will be displayed in the list. This should be
   * used to populate the list.
   * @return
   */
  List<TableProperties> retrieveContentsToDisplay() {
    TableProperties[] tpArray = TableProperties.getTablePropertiesForAll(
        getActivity(),
        TableFileUtils.getDefaultAppName());
    List<TableProperties> tpList = Arrays.asList(tpArray);
    return tpList;
  }

  /**
   * Get the list currently displayed by the fragment.
   * @return
   */
  List<TableProperties> getPropertiesList() {
    return this.mTableList;
  }

  /**
   * Update the contents of the list with the this new list.
   * @param list
   */
  void setPropertiesList(List<TableProperties> list) {
    // We can't change the reference, which is held by the adapter.
    this.getPropertiesList().clear();
    for (TableProperties tp : list) {
      this.getPropertiesList().add(tp);
    }
  }

}
```

And `fragment_table_list.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="#C0C0C0"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/no_data" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My Robolectric tests:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class TableManagerFragmentTest {

  private TableManagerFragment fragment;
  private Activity parentActivity;

  public void setupFragmentWithNoItems() {
    this.fragment = getSpy(new ArrayList<TableProperties>());
    doGlobalSetup();
  }

  public void setupFragmentWithTwoItems() {
    TableProperties tp1 = mock(TableProperties.class);
    TableProperties tp2 = mock(TableProperties.class);
    when(tp1.getDisplayName()).thenReturn("alpha");
    when(tp2.getDisplayName()).thenReturn("beta");
    List<TableProperties> listOfMocks = new ArrayList<TableProperties>();
    listOfMocks.add(tp1);
    listOfMocks.add(tp2);
    this.fragment = getSpy(listOfMocks);
    doGlobalSetup();
  }

  /**
   * Does the setup required regardless of what the fragment is returning.
   */
  public void doGlobalSetup() {
    ShadowLog.stream = System.out;
    // We need external storage available for accessing the database.
    TestCaseUtils.setExternalStorageMounted();
    startFragment(this.fragment);
    this.parentActivity = this.fragment.getActivity();
    // Have to call visible to get the fragment to think its been attached to
    // a window.
    ActivityController.of(this.parentActivity).visible();
  }

  /**
   * Get a mocked TableManagerFragment that will return toDisplay when asked to
   * retrieve TableProperties.
   * @param toDisplay
   * @return
   */
  private TableManagerFragment getSpy(List<TableProperties> toDisplay) {
     TableManagerFragment spy = spy(new TableManagerFragment());
     doReturn(toDisplay).when(spy).retrieveContentsToDisplay();
     return spy;
  }

  @Test
  public void emptyViewIsVisibleWithoutContent() {
    setupFragmentWithNoItems();
    // We aren't retrieving any TableProperties, so it is empty.
    // Weirdly, the List is also visible. Perhaps this is because the list view
    // is always visible, just not taking up any screen real estate if there
    // are no elements? Should investigate this when we have known elements.
    View emptyView = this.fragment.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
    assertThat(emptyView).isVisible();
  }

  @Test
  public void listViewIsGoneWithoutContent() {
    setupFragmentWithNoItems();
    View listView = this.fragment.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    assertThat(listView).isGone();
  }

  @Test
  public void emptyViewIsGoneWithContent() {
    setupFragmentWithTwoItems();
    View emptyView = this.fragment.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
    assertThat(emptyView).isGone();
  }

  @Test
  public void listViewIsVisibleWithContent() {
    setupFragmentWithTwoItems();
    View listView = this.fragment.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    assertThat(listView).isVisible();
  }

  @Test
  public void hasCorrectMenuItems() {
    setupFragmentWithNoItems();
    ShadowActivity shadowActivity = shadowOf(parentActivity);
    Menu menu = shadowActivity.getOptionsMenu();
    assertThat(menu)
      .hasSize(4)
      .hasItem(R.id.menu_table_manager_export)
      .hasItem(R.id.menu_table_manager_import)
      .hasItem(R.id.menu_table_manager_sync)
      .hasItem(R.id.menu_table_manager_preferences);
  }


}
```

And my failure trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ListFragment$1.run(ListFragment.java:153)
    at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.postDelayed(Scheduler.java:37)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.post(ShadowLooper.java:207)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowHandler.postDelayed(ShadowHandler.java:56)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowHandler.post(ShadowHandler.java:51)
    at android.os.Handler.post(Handler.java)
    at android.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:432)
    at android.app.ListFragment.onViewCreated(ListFragment.java:203)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:843)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
    at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.postDelayed(Scheduler.java:37)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.post(ShadowLooper.java:207)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowHandler.postDelayed(ShadowHandler.java:56)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowHandler.post(ShadowHandler.java:51)
    at android.os.Handler.post(Handler.java)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1303)
    at android.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:548)
    at android.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:532)
    at org.robolectric.util.FragmentTestUtil.startFragment(FragmentTestUtil.java:14)
    at org.opendatakit.tables.fragments.TableManagerFragmentTest.doGlobalSetup(TableManagerFragmentTest.java:60)
    at org.opendatakit.tables.fragments.TableManagerFragmentTest.setupFragmentWithNoItems(TableManagerFragmentTest.java:38)
    at org.opendatakit.tables.fragments.TableManagerFragmentTest.emptyViewIsVisibleWithoutContent(TableManagerFragmentTest.java:81)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:250)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:177)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is not robolectric's fault at all, but my own failure to understand mockito.

I was able to fix this. It isn't robolectric's problem, but my own not understanding of the mockito framework. I think somehow it boils down to problem 2 in the Spy javadoc:

> Mockito does not delegate calls to the passed real instance, instead
>   it actually creates a copy of it. So if you keep the real instance and
>   interact with it, don't expect the spied to be aware of those
>   interaction and their effect on real instance state. The corollary is
>   that when an unstubbed method is called on the spy but not on the real
>   instance, you won't see any effects on the real instance.

I'm not holding on to the real instance, but it seemed to not be doing something correctly. I ended up subclassing TableManagerFragment directly to make my own stub. It's unfortunate that I can't use Mockito to do this, although I'm not completely sure why it doesn't work. Ultimately, I don't think you can use Mockito's spy to work with Fragments. If someone can and has information to the contrary, I'd love to hear it! My life would be easier.